# Hover out delay for unintended action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to delay or stop the menu from slideUp action when a user hover off the menu by accident and then hovering again. I am trying to prevent the menu from sliding up when a user unintentionally rolls off the hover area. I want the user to hover back within a split second and not have the menu to slide up.

I used the delay function below as this does not prevent the menu from sliding up. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(250);

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).delay(1000).slideUp(500);         
    }
);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D3A5g/

Here is a suggestion Nelson posted. It work on jsfiddle but not on my pages. Can anyone tell me what is preventing from working on my page?

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xwAdG/6/

Below code does not work when I test it. Any ideas why it's not working?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#nav {
padding: 40px;
border: solid #999 1px;
}
#nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: none;
background-color: #CCC;
}
#nav ul li {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 5px;
width: 40px;
}
#nav a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px;

}
#nav a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: yellow;
}​
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {    
 over: function () { //onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED) 
    $('ul', this).slideDown(250);//show its submenu

},    
timeout: 500, // milliseconds delay before onMouseOut  (default 0)  
out: function () { // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
    $('ul', this).slideUp(500); //hide its submenu        
}     
};
$('#nav li').hoverIntent(config);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="nav">
<li ><a href="#">Main</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">AAAAA</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BBBBB</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CCCCC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">DDDDD</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FFFFF</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**: I found out that I needed to wrap the code with $(document).ready. By doing this, it worked in a html page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var config = {    
over: function () { //onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED) 
$('ul', this).slideDown(250);//show its submenu

},    
timeout: 500, // milliseconds delay before onMouseOut  (default 0)  
out: function () { // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
$('ul', this).slideUp(500); //hide its submenu        
}     
};
$('#nav li').hoverIntent(config);
});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) for that, I've use it in some projects and very happy so far.

Your posted code would be used with the plugin like this:

```
var config = {    
     over: function () { //onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED) 
        $('ul', '#nav li').slideDown(250);//show its submenu

    },    
    timeout: 0, // milliseconds delay before onMouseOut  (default 0)  
    out: function () { // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
        $('ul', '#nav li').slideUp(500); //hide its submenu        
    }     
};
$('#nav li').hoverIntent(config);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using it but not quite sure how to integrate the above code with hoverintent.js. :-(

Comment: I've updated my answer with your example code adapted to the plugin, check it out.

Comment: I have your code on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xwAdG/3/. Thanks for your help. It seems to work on jsfiddle but it does not seem to slideDown when embedded on the page. Does it require a modification when there are other ul and li on the page?

Comment: Here is the link that works but does not work when embedded on the actual page. http://jsfiddle.net/xwAdG/6/

Comment: Hi Philip, yes there was an error in my code, I've updated the code in my answer, please check it out again.

Comment: Hi Nelson. Sorry but the update code still does not seem to work. Please try it for yourself.

Comment: I was told that it was not working due to the missing $(document).ready(function() {